# des3526, how do I untag vlan ports?

Tags: vlan, d-link

I am trying to configure a D-link DES 3526 switch. When I add a VLAN with some untagged ports (via the web interface), the system says that it cannot add untagged vlan ports. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have 1 untagged vlan per port, on a port setup for access.  On a port setup for truncking you can have 1 untagged and as many tagged vlans as you like.  If you want to switch which vlan is untagged simply go to the other vlan and mark that port as untagged.